# Deja Dup Backup Failure

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I'm trying to Backup Now with Deja Dup, but get a failure soon after starting.

Backup Failed
Failed to retrieve share list from server: No such file or directory

It doesn't tell me which file or directory it can not find. I have no way to correct the error. And which server is providing the share list?

Every thing looks good as to what folders to include, which folders to exclude and where to store the backup.

Any suggestions to correct the failure?

Comment: Found solution. In a terminal window gained with Ctrl-Alt-t, enter the following: dconf reset -f "/org/gnome/deja-dup/"  Then restart deja-dup, enter the folders to be included, and the folders to be excluded, and where the backup is to be stored. In the overview window select Backup Now. This worked for me. A new backup was created in the location specified with those files which were to be included.